# Defining a natural metric to say that two vectors are pointing at one another or pointing away from one another

Tags: geometry, mathematical-physics

I am developing a software, and it is heavily reliant on "orientations" of particles in the system. Take the following diagram for example.
[image]

I have two particles at location $A$ and $B$, in 3D space. The have vector orientations $o_1$ and $o_2$ (that are also 3D). The vector $d=B-A$ is the vector joining points A and B. The two particles at $A$ and $B$ interact with each other with energy between $E^a$ (aligned) and $E^{a'}$ (not aligned). A *perfectly aligned* interaction is shown in the center configurations -- the orientations are antiparallel to one another, and pointing at one another. Hence, the energy of interaction between particles is $E^a$. The configuration in the right most image is perfectly *not aligned* and the energy of the interaction is $E^{a'}$. If the two orientation are parallel, I have the midpoint of the interactions, $(E^a+E^{a'})/2$, as seen in the leftmost figure.

- *I am looking for a norm that captures how "aligned" or how "not aligned" two vectors are.*

So that I can set up an energy function which goes like
\begin{align}
E = xE^{a'} + (1-x) E^a \text{ or } E = (1-x)E^{a'} + xE^a
\end{align}
where $x$ is a measure for how aligned or how misaligned the two vectors are. So far I have come with
$$ x = \frac{\sin \left( \frac{\theta _2 - \theta _1}{2} \right)+1}{2}$$
where $\theta_1$ is the anticlockwise angle between $d$ and $o_1$ and $\theta _2$ is the angle between $d$ and $o_2$. This at first glance makes sense in $2D$, but I start seeing counterexamples once I hit 3D. For example, if I rotate $o_2$ goes out of plane and into the positive z-axis, the angle between d and $o_2$ is still 90, but it is further away from the tip of $o_1$. How do I account for non-planarity and the fuzziness it brings to my measure $x$? I assume I have to include angles between planes to metric $x$, but I do not how to do it.

Any advice you have for me will be appreciated!

Comment: It's difficult to guess what you would like to get in situations which are not the center picture or the righmost picture. E.g. what energy would you like to get in the leftmost picture? Note that two parallel vectors are "aligned", so in the 3 pictures the two vectors are aligned.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni, thank you for your response. You are right, that is bad nomenclature on my part. If two vectors are parallel/aligned, I would like the midpoint, so $x=1/2$.

Comment: Please also note that vectors have no fixed position in space. Notably, the angle of two vectors stays the same whatever the begin points of each vector are. So "it is further away from the tip of $o1$" has no meaning, when talking about vectors...

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni, looking at the center image and rightmost image, though, is it fair to say that the orientation tips are closer in the center but further for the rightmost =? That is the notion of distance I want to convey...

Comment: Oh, OK. I had not understood that. Then the energy you are looking for is function of the distance between the "vectors tips", isn't it?

Comment: Yes. that is fair to say. however, how do I do it? for example, the energy of interaction between two particles along the body diagonal of the cube pointing at one another should be the same as the energy of two particles along a simple edge, with their orientations pointing back at them

Comment: Why not have the total energy as the sum of two energies, one measuring how aligned $A$'s orientation is with $d$ and the other measuring the same for $B$? Each of these two energies involves only a plane, so the problem goes away.

Comment: that is an interesting suggestion @GregMartin, thank you! Could you possibly elaborate on how you would go about it?

Comment: @GregMartin, I do not seem to understand how your method seems to resolve the problem of two parallel orientations. If possible, could you write your method down as an answer?

Comment: The energy should be proportional to something, but to what? I have still not understood, which means it is difficult to come up with a mathematical formula... ;-)

Comment: the energy must be proportional to how "well the two orientations are pointing at one another" and on how "close the two points are on the lattice". If they are perfectly pointing at one other, then they have an aligned interaction, if they are perfectly pointing away from one another, that is misaligned. I guess, that is the best explanation I have right now...